# Exclude weekends in python django query set

Tags: python, django

I want to filter some dates that will exclude weekends.
I already have a list of days in weekends

and I would like to create a query that will filter these days.
I have a date field in the model which is

```
Class Sample(models.Model)
    date=models.DateField()

weekends = [2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24]
Sample.objects.filter(date__month=month).exclude(date__day=weekends)
```

I can do this using a for loop though, but the code would suck.. 
I was wondering if there are any one line filtering techniques available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IN clause.

```
Sample.objects.filter(date__month=month).exclude(date__day__in = weekends)
```

From django soruce code of DateField:

```
def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
    # For "__month", "__day", and "__week_day" lookups, convert the value
    # to an int so the database backend always sees a consistent type.
    if lookup_type in ('month', 'day', 'week_day'):
        return int(value)
```

So ideally `__day` should work. Can you also try to change your field name from `date` to something like `created_date` to avoid namespace clashes?

Comment: hmm I already did this. And I get this error: "Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'day' for the lookup type?"

Comment: i see... so maybe it had issues with the field name. well yeah I can but that would mean i have to edit different files again.

Thanks btw. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *in* operator:

```
Sample.objects.filter(Q(date__month=month)).exclude(Q(date__day__in=weekends))
```

Comment: hmm I already did this. And I get this error:

Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'day' for the lookup type?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have this figured out. `exclude(date__day__in=weekends)` doesn't work. I don't know maybe the complicated look-up messes up when using the in query.

So what I did is create some dates using those days. And did something like

```
Sample.objects.filter(Q(date__month=month)).exclude(Q(date__in=weekends))
```